# How to get Flask-SQLAlchemy to work with the Application Factory Pattern

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to set up an sqlite database using Flask-SQLAlchemy. I am getting an Operational error `(sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table`.

This is for a Web app written with flask. I want to interact with the database using Flask-SQLAlchemy extension. I feel it may be something to do with the application context, but I am not sure.

As you can see the application has one 'module' (the `auth` sub-package). The module is registered to the application via a blueprint. I define the model for the `Researcher` class in the `models.py` file of the `auth` sub-package. `app/__init__.py` holds the Application Factory and the database initialization. 
Because I am just trying to get the basic functionality working, the only two views I have are defined in `app/auth/routes.py`.

---

```
.
|-- app
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- auth
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- __pycache__
|   |   |-- models.py
|   |   `-- routes.py
|   |-- static
|   `-- templates
|-- app.db
|-- config.py
|-- instance
|   `-- config.py
`-- run.py
```

## app/**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_pyfile("../config.py")

    db.init_app(app)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

    from app.auth import auth
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix="/auth/")

    return app
```

## app/auth/routes.py

```
from flask import Flask
from app import db
from models import User
from app.auth import auth

@auth.route("/insert")
def insert():
    #r = Reasearcher("Pat","Den", "Pat_Den@mail.com", "operator","Dr.","Mr", "08611111", "+353", "0001")
    u = User(1,"Elija")
    db.session.add(u)
    db.session.commit()

@auth.route("/query")
def query():
    us = users.query.all()
    s = ""
    for u in us:
        s += u.name
    return s
```

## app/auth/models.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from app import db

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)

    def __init__(self,ids, name):
        self.id = ids
        self.name = name
```

## app/auth/**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint

auth = Blueprint("auth", __name__)

import routes
import models
```

## config.py

```
DEBUG = True

import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "sqlite:////" + os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "app.db")
DATABASE_CONNECT_OPTIONS = {}
THREADS_PER_PAGE = 2

CSRF_ENABLED     = True

CSRF_SESSION_KEY = "secret"
SECRET_KEY = "secret"
```

I should be able to request /auth/query and get the contents of the database table, but instead I get the error -
"OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: researchers [SQL: u'INSERT INTO researchers (prefix, suffix, phone, phone_ext, orcid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: ('Dr.', 'Mr', '08611111', '+353', '0001')] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)"

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the point that code is doing `db.create_all()`, models haven't been imported. Importing them has the side-effect of populating some data structures that SQLAlchemy uses behind the scenes. If the `db.create_all()` happens before SQLAlchemy knows about models, it thinks there's nothing to do.

Try this: In `__init__.py`, remove `with app.appcontext(): db.create_all()` and add `import models` to the bottom. Then add a management command to `run.py`. It'll look something like

```
app = create_app()

@app.cli.command()
def createdb():
    db.create_all()
```

Then

```
FLASK_APP=run.py flask createdb
```

will create tables.

Comment: Thank you so much, i fixed the issue by simply registering the blueprints first and then `with app.appcontext(): db.create all()`. I guess I have to import all models by registering blueprints and then execute `create_db`. I am using the 'flask run' command to run a test server and forgot to take run.py out. I am unfamiliar with the @app.cli.command() thing. Would you still recommend that method over just doing it in the application factory?

Comment: Using a separate management command (via `@app.cli.command`) gives you  control over when, say, database migrations happen. I use them to run my migrations, then I'll run tests, and if all is clear, finally the app. I find that it's quicker to fix a problem if tests suss one out.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't been able to reproduce your issues, but this was working for me.

In your your app folder:
    python3 -m venv venv
    source venv/bin/activate
    pip install flask flask_sqlalchemy
    pip install -e .
    flask run

`__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_pyfile("../config.py")

    db.init_app(app)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

        import auth
        app.register_blueprint(auth.routes.auth, url_prefix="/auth/")

        return app
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='yourapplication',
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        'flask',
        ],
    )
```

auth/`__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint

import auth.routes
import auth.models
```

auth/models.py

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from app import db
from auth.models import Researcher

auth = Blueprint("auth", __name__)

@auth.route("/insert")
def insert():
    #r = Reasearcher("Pat","Den", "Pat_Den@mail.com", "operator","Dr.","Mr", "08611111", "+353", "0001")
    r = Researcher("Dr.","Mr", "08611111", "+353", "0001")
    db.session.add(r)
    db.session.commit()

    @auth.route("/query")
    def query():
        rs = Researcher.query.all()
        s = ""
        for r in rs:
            s += r.prefix + " " + r.phone
            return s
```

auth/routes.py

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from app import db
from auth.models import Researcher

auth = Blueprint("auth", __name__)

@auth.route("/insert")
def insert():
    #r = Reasearcher("Pat","Den", "Pat_Den@mail.com", "operator","Dr.","Mr", "08611111", "+353", "0001")
    r = Researcher("Dr.","Mr", "08611111", "+353", "0001")
    db.session.add(r)
    db.session.commit()

    @auth.route("/query")
    def query():
        rs = Researcher.query.all()
        s = ""
        for r in rs:
            s += r.prefix + " " + r.phone
            return s
```

Comment: I have actually changed it since posting it. I took out all the models and inserted one simple one called user which has an id like above and one attribute. I have altered the query and insert to match it. I am still getting a "no such table" error.

Comment: @Ronan can you update you update the post with your current code along with where you are seeing the error (console or flask debug ui)? I wasn't able to reproduce your error

Comment: Ive updated the code and added a screenshot of the flask debugger

Comment: @Ronan I haven't been able to use your code to reproduce the error. I updated my answer which worked for me. Hopefully that helps a little :)

Comment: The auth/models.py file in this example is actually just the contents auth/routes.py file, which is unfortunate because I'm looking for an example of how to write the models file with the app factory pattern.