# Importing multiple models in create_app method

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a base flask app that I have put together to build future projects from.  I have it set up with an application factory method "create_app".

[https://github.com/thenetimp/flask_base_v2/blob/master/app/**init**.py#L1-L32](https://github.com/thenetimp/flask_base_v2/blob/master/app/__init__.py#L1-L32)

In the create_app method, I am initializing the application object.  Then pass it to the previously initialized db object eventually calling db.create_all to create the database from my model(s).

In order for this to work I have to import any model I may have into the create_app function.  This isn't problematic for a small database with a few tables, but if I have a database with a large number of tables it seems like there should be a better way.  `from app.models import *` doesn't work inside functions, so I have to ask is there another way to manage this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54487519/how-to-get-flask-sqlalchemy-to-work-with-the-application-factory-pattern

Comment: Similar problem but not entirely a duplicate, eitherway I just figured out what I needed to change and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

in the code I was trying to do

```
def create_app():
     from app.models import *
     ...
```

when all I needed to do was

```
def create_app():
     import app.models
     ...
```

get so use to doing it one way I forgot about the other.